# Is there such expression as "Charlie someone out"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang, phrase-meaning, offensive-language

There is the following exchange in Deadwood series season 1 episode 3

> ...
>
> Johnny: Al?
>
> Al: Yeah.
>
> Johnny: That cherry New York dude is downstairs askin’ for ya.
>
> Al: No good. **Charlie him the fuck out**.
>
> (Johnny approaches Al’s side)
>
> Johnny: He keeps talkin’ about the Pinkertons.
>
> ...

I am interested in the expression from the title, while meaning is perfectly clear from the context I am wondering is this a real expression (meaning do people actually use it like this).
I have found two ([1](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Charlie%20Out) and [2](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Charlie%20The%20Fuck%20Up)) entries in urbandictionary, but they both are neither here nor there.

Comment: In AmE, "Chuck" is a pet name for Charles so "Charlie him...out." could be interpreted as "Chuck him...out" (i.e. eject him from the bar).

Comment: Googling reveals that, even if it is, it's widely unpopular. Perhaps, this was just a one-off artistic-licence thing.

Comment: @KillingTime That seems to fit the William.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I should send you a Diet Coke for that one!

Comment: @Hot Licks Probably a wasted (though kind) gesture over here. We're only allowed one bubble apiece.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Just don't run up a Tab.

Comment: @KillingTime: Given that Swearengen is English, the Chuck/Charlie substitution could be a variation on the word substitution that you find in England (most notably cockneys). It's not quite the same, but similar enough while remaining understandable to Dan and Johnny.